# addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView quando acedendo à atividade "Home"

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Estou a desenvolver um carrinho de compras para Android a usar Firebase e estou a ter problemas usando o RecycleView, uma vez que a atividade está a crashar após o login do user, produzindo o seguinte erro.

**Log**

```
05-24 17:38:02.156 9775-9775/com.cars.evd.dealership E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cars.evd.dealership, PID: 9775
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:500)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:166)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:641)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

**Home.java**

```
package com.cars.evd.dealership.main;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Common.Common;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Model.Category;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.ViewHolder.CarsViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;

    //Load Menu
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //Initialise Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category = database.getReference("Category");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Set a name for the user
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentuser.getName());

        //Menu Load
       recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
       recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
       layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       loadMenu();

    }

    private void loadMenu() {


         FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CarsViewHolder> adapter = new
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CarsViewHolder>(Category.class, R.layout.car_selection, CarsViewHolder.class,category) {

                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(CarsViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                        final Category clickItem = model;
                        viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                                Toast.makeText(Home.this,""+clickItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**CarsViewHolder**

```
package com.cars.evd.dealership.main.ViewHolder;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.R;



public class CarsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtMenuName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    public CarsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtMenuName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_name);
        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a sua questão e coloque o código da classe `CarsViewHolder`

Comment: Pedido acedido.